# Mark repository as fork, if it has copied manully

Tags: git, git-fork

I'm new to Git and made a stupid thing: I had a project A, then **manually** copied it for new project B (without git folder), created a new repository and worked simultaneously in both.

Is any way to set a project B as a **fork** for A now?

ps: I need it to exchange commits between projects, and, it seems, patches are not a solution.

**UPD 11.07:** As i said the main purpose was to "move" some commits from B to A and vise-versa.

**UPD 13.07:** Moved solution to answers

Comment: Should be simple; trash B, clone A into B.

Comment: Jack, What about commits in B?

Comment: It depends on how diverged both code bases are, but you could run a diff on both projects and apply selective changes to A first.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand properly: with diff i apply some changes to A (don't i?), but what about commits that should be only in B?

Comment: By fork, do you mean "clone"? Or fork as in GitHub fork?

Comment: VonC, not clone, as GitHub fork.

Comment: Jack, i wanted to try your variant, but when came back to do so, you deleted it... So i has to find some other option. It seems worked. But was it the simpliest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this:

1. List item
2. Pushed **A_local** and **B_local** to own **A_remote** and **B_remote_tmp** repositaries on BitBucket
3. Forked an **A_remote** as **B_remote_new** and cloned on computer as **B_local_new**
4. Set **B_remote_tmp** as remote for **B_local** on local repositary
5. Checked out as local branch **B_remote_tmp** and merged it to **B_local**.
6. Pushed **B_local** to **B_remote_new** and deleted **B_remote_tmp**

This saved a commit messages and now i have **B** as fork to **A**. Then i did this for copying changes from B to A:

1. On local cloned repositary **A_local** i set **B_remote_new** as remote and checked it out as local branch.
2. Cherry-picked all nessessary commits from **B** using a branch for usability and pushed it.

It's not the easiest way, but simple to understand for me and, as i see, it worked. =) Now I have two repositaries, where one is fork of another with all commits history. Using branches and BitBucked interface i can apply new changes from one to another (both repositaries are shown in pull requests window).

ps: I didn't find a way to set a local repositary as remote to another local one and i'm already used a BitBucked - that's why i chose it. And i think same thing could be done in github too.

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about carrying across the changes, but not the specific commit history...

Just delete your .git directory from B and copy the .git directory from A to B and you're more or less done.

Git will now identify all the changes you've made in B as unstaged changes. Stage them and commit them, and, if you want to share code between them, set A as a remote for B:

```
$ cd b-dir
$ git remote add origin path/to/a-dir
```

Comment: But if I delete .git folder from B  I'll lose all commits from there.

Comment: Do you care? You can make a single commit which captures the current state of the repository, no changes are lost.

Comment: Perhaps he means that the commit messages will be gone? In any case, this solution looks better than mine, so +1 :)

Comment: It's simple way, but as i mentioned - i wanted to save messages, and further copy selected commits to another repositary.